# How do I correct errors in album/work/song/track in Gracenote after the CD is already imported into iTunes?

Tags: itunes, music

While a CD is importing, I can select tracks, Get Info, edit, and Submit CD Track Names... (which apparently submits many of the other fields).

But if there are too many errors to get before the import finishes, what then?  I don't find the submit on any other menu or screen except the import, which doesn't exist when not importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha!  If I turn off the eject after import option (which the latest update turned off without asking me!), then the import window stays there and I can continue to edit and submit.

Or, I can say **No** to the import, do my editing, submit corrections, then Import.

Third option, re-insert the CD, make corrections, submit, re-import (it will ask me whether I want to replace the previously imported files).

(Unfortunately, it won't let me edit some tags, but that's another question.)